# Unable to mock static methods using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, static, jmockit

I am writing a testcase which includes to mock a static method. Though not able to achieve the desired result.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

import mockit.Mock;
import mockit.MockUp;
import mockit.Mocked;

public class MockSubClassTest {


@Test
public void mockSuperClassTest(@Mocked final SuperClass superClass){

    new MockUp<Util>() {
        @Mock
        public String getAppName(){
            return "FXI";
        }
    };



    SubClass subClass = new SubClass("data"); 
    assertEquals("data", subClass.getData());

    assertEquals("FXI", subClass.getApp());

}
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

String data;

public SubClass(String string) {
    super(string);
    data = string;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;

}

}


public class SuperClass {

public final static String app = Util.getAppName();

public SuperClass(String data) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}


public String getApp(){
    return app;
}
}

public class Util {

public static TestObject getObject() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public static String getAppName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

But while asserting for getAppName, it is failing. In the above code, I am able to mock super class constructor but unable to mock Util.getAppName().

I am new to JMockit, hence would appreciate help.

Comment: i mocked the super class hence I believe the Util was never initialized. As after removing the mockup of super class, I am able to use Util mockup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `SuperClass` is `@Mocked` so the `MockUp<Util>` is not applied.

This works as expected (changes commented out):

```
public void mockSuperClassTest(/*@Mocked final SuperClass superClass*/) {
  //same code here
}

class SuperClass {
  public final static String app = Util.getAppName();
  public SuperClass(String data) {
    //throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  public String getApp() {
    return app;
  }
}
```